# Рекурсия  jquery после Ajax запроса в Wordpress

Tags: ajax, php, wordpress

Доброго времени суток. Сразу оговорюсь php и ajax только изучаю и прерываю кучу документов но вот столкнулся с проблемой в чем проблема уже понял оказалось что проблема в том что ajax  запрос заново dom  элементы на которые надо заново вешать обработчики но проблема в том что созданный элемент опять же через гет запрос опять создает новый элемент на который опять надо вешать обработчик события итак вот код

```
<div class='phones'>
<?php $cartHeader = selectAll();
    foreach($cartHeader as $item){
        echo "<div class='phone'>";
        echo "<p class='numberForHeaderCart'>".$item["number"]."</p>";
        echo "<p class='priceForHeaderCart'>".$item['price']." руб. </p>";
        echo "<a class='delCart' href='#'>X</a>";
        echo "<p class='displayNone'>".$item['id']."</p>";
        echo "<div class='clear'></div>";
        echo "</div>";
    }?>
</div>
```

документ script.js

```
jQuery('.delCart').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var delID = jQuery(this).parents('.phone').children('.displayNone').text();  ;
   jQuery.get("/script/scriptHeader.php",
   {
        id:delID},
        function(dataH){jQuery("#headerCart").html(dataH);});
   jQuery.get("/script/scriptCart.php",
         {id:delID},
         function(dataHS){jQuery("#theCart").html(dataHS);});  
     });
```

два get запроса надо потому что удаляется с двух мест документ scriptHeader.php

```
<?php include('addToCart.php' ); 
include('deleteFromCart.php' ); ?>
<div id='headerCart' class='cartouter span4'>
    <div class='cart'>
      <div  class='text'>
          <p class='dark_blue'>В корзине</p>
          <p class='dark_blue'>Всего в корзине</p>
          <p class='dark_blue'>Итого на сумму</p>   
      </div>
      <div class='sum'>
            <p class='red'></p>
            <p class='yelow'><?=$count;?></p>
            <p class='white'><?php echo $sumCart;?></p>
      </div>
      <div class='backcart'></div>
      <a href='/cart.php' class='button'>Оформить заказ</a>
      <div class='phones'>
         <?php $cartHeader = selectAll();
         foreach($cartHeader as $item){
            echo "<div class='phone'>";
              echo "<p class='numberForHeaderCart'>".$item["number"]."</p>";
              echo "<p class='priceForHeaderCart'>".$item['price']." руб. </p>";
              echo "<a class='delCart' href='#'>X</a>";
              echo "<p class='displayNone'>".$item['id']."</p>";
              echo "<div class='clear'></div>";
              echo "</div>";}
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

документ deleteFromCart.php

```
<?php 
        $id=$_GET["id"]; 
        cartDel($id);
 ?>
```

функция cartDel();

```
function cartDel($id){
    global $wpdb;
    $sql= "DELETE FROM wp_cart WHERE id=$id";
    $wpdb->query($sql);}
```

первоначально код (не то что бы не реальный, но из него вырезаны практически все скрипты wordperss) при нажатии на ссылку 
<a class='delCart' href='#'>X</a> 
первый раз  срабатывал и строка удаляется, а второй раз при клике на эту ссылку ни чего не происходит.Я перерыв кучу документов уже осознал в чем проблема. Но как решить пока не знаю дело в том что я не знаю сколько у меня будет элементов которые надо удалять я написал (как думал) callback функцию но она отрабатывается все го  дважды а мне надо что бы обрабатывалась столько сколько нужно.  Код который написал выглядит так.script.js

```
 jQuery('.delCart').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var delID = jQuery(this).parent('.phone').children('.displayNone').text();  
    alert(delID);
    jQuery.get("<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/script/scriptHeader.php",
    {id:delID},
    function(dataH){
        jQuery("#headerCart").html(dataH);
        jQuery('.delCart').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var delID = jQuery(this).parent('.phone').children('.displayNone').text();  
            alert(delID);
            jQuery.get("<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/script/scriptHeader.php",
            {id:delID},
            function(dataH){
                jQuery("#headerCart").html(dataH);});
                jQuery.get("<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/script/scriptCart.php",
                {id:delID},
                function(dataHS){jQuery("#theCart").html(dataHS);}); 
                        });
                    });
                jQuery.get("<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/script/scriptCart.php",
                {id:delID},
                function(dataHS){jQuery("#theCart").html(dataHS);}); 
            });
```

Можете подсказать как и в идеале помочь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не отвечу на ваш вопрос целиком, но можно хотя бы минимум упростить себе жизнь и передать ID в ссылку по которой кликаете

```
echo "<a class='delCart' href='#".$item['id']."'>X</a>";
echo "<p class='displayNone'>".$item['id']."</p>";//"Эту строчку удалить
```

и после клика на крестик получаем нужный ID

```
var delID = jQuery(this).attr('href').replace(/[^0-9]+/, '');
```

Могу предположить что в строке получения ID и есть весь трабл так как вы используете

```
var delID = jQuery(this).parents <- //parents а не parent
```

и передаете не верный ID в запрос.

Comment: @Palmervan, только лучше в атрибут data-*, а то replace - лишнее телодвижение.

Comment: думаю дело не в том такое ощущение что не исполняется скрипт из документа scriptHeader.php то есть при том что я нажимаю на ссылку в строке появляется #  то есть не работает даже e.preventDefault();.

Comment: И я по побывал не получилось :(

Comment: Что же ваш ответ был на и более  верным проблема в том что при аякс запросе добавляются элементы к DOM -дереву но события jquery к ни м не привязываються по этому я вышел из ситуации путем создания функции и запуска её через событие .live()

Answer (score 0):

Если e.preventDefault не срабатывает, откройте консоль в браузере, посмотрите ошибки javascript.

Comment: в том и прикол что все нормально ни чего не показывает . Да и ещё забыл описать. При смене #theCart текст меняет кодировку на какую не пойму. хотя везде стоит utf-8 без БОМ

Comment: отправьте url, где можно посмотреть это всё

Comment: А разве можно это же ссылка на реальный сайт который работает здесь за это бан не будет.

Comment: причем кодировка меняется только на локальном сервере. На реальном адресе ничего не меняется.